# Colocar uma string em um valor booleano

Tags: c#, .net, string, tipagem, condição

Como mostra *string* no operador ternário?

```
String aluno, aprovado, reprovado; 
      Console.WriteLine("Digite um número:");
      aluno = Console.ReadLine();

      Double media, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4;
      media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4)/4;

      Boolean decisao,true,false;
      true = "Aprovado;"
      false = "Reprovado";

      decisao = media >= 5?  true : false;
      Console.WriteLine ($"{aluno} tem média {media} está: {decisao}.");
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Esse código não faz muito sentido e está cheio de coisas incoerentes. Uma parte acredito que vá completar depois (acho que errará na conversão de dados, fica a dica quando for fazer, pesquise sobre).

Em primeiro lugar não use palavras chave como nome de variáveis. Na verdade não crie variáveis sem necessidade. Entenda para que serve uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Não é que não possa usar palavras chave como variáveis, mas fica feio e isso só deve ser usado em código complexos que o nome precisa muito ser essa palavra para ser mais legível. Seu código cria confusão e fica menos legível. Você consegue dar uma justificativa plausível para criar uma variável para colocar um texto que será usado apenas uma vez e que o conteúdo dele não muda e é óbvio? Pior, por que ele precisa usar essas palavras chave?

Sem justificativas plausíveis não faça nada no seu código.

Na verdade esse código nem compila, assim funcionaria, ainda que a média será fixa.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Digite um número:");
        var aluno = ReadLine();
        var nota1 = 0.0;
        var nota2 = 0.0;
        var nota3 = 0.0;
        var nota4 = 0.0;
        var media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4) / 4;
        WriteLine ($"{aluno} tem média {media} está: {(media >= 5 ?  "Aprovado" : "Reprovado")}.");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GjFyvi). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AuhZfQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Variable.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Vou responder sua pergunta:

> Como mostra string no operador ternário?

```cs
bool var1;

var1 = true;

Console.WriteLine(var1?"Verdadeiro":"Falso");

var1 = false;

Console.WriteLine(var1?"Verdadeiro":"Falso");
```

Agora se você quer usar palavras reservadas como nome de variável é só colocar arroba na frente:

```cs
var @true = "Verdadeiro";

var @object = "Objeto";

var @byte = "Byte";

var @new = "Novo";

var @dynamic = "Dinâmico";
```

E isso não é só para `strings`, qualquer tipo de objeto.